# MySQL: Assessing performance of a query by using EXPLAIN

Tags: mysql

It is said that the number of rows are scanned is smaller the performance is higher when use Explain to optimize query. So I wonder

- When the EXPLAIN output includes many rows, is there any formula to
  calculate the total number of rows which is scanned? After searching
  on internet, it seems the total number of rows is the product of
  values of all rows in EXPLAIN output. But does it makes sense in case
  we use UNION?
- Are there another criteria we should combine with 'rows' column in EXPLAIN output to know performance of query? Because if the formula is multiplying all number of rows, there are some cases the time execute the query is faster but the total number of rows is scanned is larger.

Comment: I always spot check the number of rows to see that it makes sense.  EXPLAIN is just the query optimizer's goal for the task.  There are many other factors that go into performance (column types, truly proper indexing, disk IO, etc.).